# Extract values from nested json

Tags: json, angular, primeng

I have a json with which I am using with PrimeNG tree to populate the component and I want to extract only the "label" values (which are the nodes for the tree).

I want to make an autocomplete input when adding a category label in the tree, the user can select the parent where the category will go (this will autocomplete with parent path)

How can I extract and output like this:
Documents -> Work

Documents -> Home

Pictures

and so on...   ??

```
    {
    "data": 
    [
        {
            "label": "Documents",
            "data": "Documents Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [{
                    "label": "Work",
                    "data": "Work Folder",
                    "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                    "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                    "children": [{"label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Expenses Document"}, {"label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Resume Document"}]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Home",
                    "data": "Home Folder",
                    "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                    "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                    "children": [{"label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Invoices for this month"}]
                }]
        },
        {
            "label": "Pictures",
            "data": "Pictures Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [
                {"label": "barcelona.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "Barcelona Photo"},
                {"label": "logo.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeFaces Logo"},
                {"label": "primeui.png", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeUI Logo"}]
        },
        {
            "label": "Movies",
            "data": "Movies Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [{
                    "label": "Al Pacino",
                    "data": "Pacino Movies",
                    "children": [{"label": "Scarface", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Scarface Movie"}, {"label": "Serpico", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Serpico Movie"}]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Robert De Niro",
                    "data": "De Niro Movies",
                    "children": [{"label": "Goodfellas", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Goodfellas Movie"}, {"label": "Untouchables", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Untouchables Movie"}]
                }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so what you want is when the user select the parent label, the list of children label to come up?

Comment: When the user want to add a Category(node) he must select the parent (for example in autocomplete when he type home to apear Documents -> Home the whole path)

Comment: How can i extract all the keys with labels? I tried this code but does not go deeper in json.
[code]
for (var i in this.filesTree4) {
      var obj = this.filesTree4[i];
      for (var label in obj) {
        if(label === 'label')
          console.log(obj[label]);
      }
    }
[/code]
the output is only the first tree:Documents, Pictures,Movies

Comment: i'm still not sure what you're trying to do, are you trying to get the label of the parents and the labels of all children?

Comment: I would like to create another json like this for this example:
"parent": "Documents", 
"parent": "Documents -> Work",
"parent": "Documents -> Home",
"parent": "Pictures",
"parent": "Movies",
"parent": "Movies -> Al Pacino",
"parent": "Movies -> Robert De Niro"